# SSRS Expression shows #Error while replacing brackets "(" ")"

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, dynamics-crm, ssrs-2012

I am writing an expression to replace sub string.

I am developing a SSRS report for Microsoft Dynamics 365 using FetchXML. I have a grid on report shows related rows of a record.

I have to remove everything inside brackets.

I have written an expression, it is working good if value contains Brackets but not when value does not contains brackets.

```
=IIF(InStr(Fields!deal_name.Value, "(") = 0, Fields!deal_name.Value, Replace(Fields!deal_name.Value,Mid(Fields!deal_name.Value,InStr(Fields!deal_name.Value, "("),InStr(Fields!deal_name.Value, ")")),""))
```

Original Values:
[image]

After Expression Result:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because Iif evaluates all expressions even when false

You can use regular expression replace

```
=  System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(Fields!deal_name.Value , "[(].*[)]", "")
```

Comment: I want to remove everything inside the bracket including brackets, This expression removes brackets and keeps the contents inside the bracket

Comment: Thanks a Million!